# Modify each item from Flowable<List<Item>> depending on another Flowable<List<Item2>> in RxJava

Tags: rx-java2

I have 3 methods in my Room Database

```
Flowable<List<Book>> getBooks() {....}
Flowable<List<Author>> getAuthors(int bookId) {....}
Flowable<List<Category>> getCategories(int bookId) {....}
```

The Book object

```
Book {int id; List<Author> authors; List<Category> categories}
```

I am trying to do something like

```
Flowable<List<Book>> getBookFullBooks() {
    return getBooks()
    //1. get the list of books from flowable??
    //2. get each book from the list??
    //3. set properties of each book from getAuthors(book.id) and 
    //   getCategories(book.id)
    // Something like:
        .switchMap(book -> _getCategories(book.id).map(categories -> {
            book.categories = categories;
            return book;
        }))
       .switchMap(book -> _getAuthors(book.id).map(authors -> {
           book.authors = authors;
           return book;
       }));// collect the books into a sequentioal Flowable<List<Book>>
}
//4. then return all the books as Flowable<List<Book>>
```

I have been trying to do so but without any success. How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
getBooks()
    .flatMapSingle(bookList -> Flowable.fromIterable(bookList)
        .flatMap(book -> getCategories(book.id)
            .map(categories -> {
                   book.setCategories(categories);
                   return book;
            }))
        .flatMap(book -> getAuthors(book.id)
            .map(authors -> {
                   book.setAuthors(authors);
                   return book;
             }))
          .toList())
    .subscribe(bookList -> {
        // done
    });
```

I think it didn't work on the first time because your `Flowable<List<Book>>` didn't complete and `toList()` got stuck. Try to nest the flatMaps, it should work not because `Flowable.fromIterable()` completes after its done looping.

I created test like this and it works fine
https://pastebin.com/Fus4MvXW

Comment: Will this preserve the order of 'bookList' ?

Comment: I tried the code after adding .toFlowable (as the Function returns flowable) the subscriber is not getting any values

Comment: What is Flowable<List<Book>> it is  continuously emitting values upon change or is it cold observable? If it's the first it will not work, wait I'll edit my answer

Comment: And why are you using `toFlowable()` anywhere? Use version of flatMap that takes `Publisher`, and you won't need any conversion

Comment: And yes, it will preserve order

Comment: Still not getting any data

Comment: Hmm, I noticed toList() returns `Single` so I changed version of `flatMap` to `flatMapSingle`. I created a test and works fine https://pastebin.com/Fus4MvXW